# IIS 10 : MS Server 2016 : ColdFusion 2016 : 500 Server Error

Tags: windows-server-2016, iis-10, coldfusion-2016

I got ColdFusion 2016 installed on MS Server 2016 running IIS 10.

The ColdFusion Administrator Runs Fine off the local IP.
http://127.0.0.1:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm etc etc...

The websites when setup display .htm and .html files correctly.

But for the .cfm files I am getting:

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Not sure if a Mime Type etc... Reviewing the 2012 Server there are no .cfm mime types.

Any ideas folks.  I find options for older CF10 or IIS8 etc. But nthing specific to my configuration yet.

Thx

I am reviewing

2. The not showing .cfm is a ColdFusion Update Issue. Happens after some CF Updates.

   Run the command-line interface

   Open a console window.

   Change to the cf_root/runtime/bin (server configuration) or jrun_root/bin (multiserver configuration) directory.

   Execute the wsconfig.exe (Windows) or wsconfig (UNIX) command:

   Choose "Upgrade" : it worked

Now the 500 Error - likely permissions

Comment: If I recall - this is a ColdFusion Update issue - and I need to run a config file or something - searching for resolve

Answer (score 1):

500 Internal Server Error

Was a Permission Setting - I set sharing to Everyone : Read

Comment: Is your problem solved? If it is solved, please share your answer so that you can help more people who have similar problems.